# Hint on power sum coefficients

Tags: summation

Please *do not* give anything more than a tiny hint for this question.

I know that there is a well-known formula for $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^k,$$ where $k$ is any non-negative integer. I have been able to prove that in fact it is a polynomial in $n$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^k = \sum_{j=0}^{k+1} a_j n^j,$$
with high-order term $\frac 1 {k+1} n^{k+1}$ and zero constant term. In the process, I found a rather awkward method of calculating the rest of the coefficients. I'm now trying to figure out what the rest of them are. So far, I've gotten
$$a_j = \frac{k!}{j!(k-j+1)!}-\sum_{m=j+1}^{k+1}a_{m}\frac{m!}{j!(m-j+1)!},$$
where $a_j$ is the coefficient of $n^j$ (for $j\le k$). Can someone give me a tiny hint on how to proceed? Please *do not* go and tell me what the coefficients are, or how the rest of the proof goes, or anything like that.

Comment: Since you specifically said not to say what the coefficients are etc, I will just make a small comment here. These coefficients are complicated and its very hard to get a explicit formula. Bernoulli was able to get an expression for it and it is closely related to Bernoulli numbers.

Comment: Agreed. I would be amazed if you can guess the formula by just staring at a few initial values. Something related that you can work on, is to show that the sum of coefficients is 1.

Comment: @PratyushSarkar: unfortunately, the Wikipedia article on Bernoulli numbers seems (based on the links on top) to have more information about this problem than I want to see just yet...

Comment: @CalvinLin Wow, that's a pretty amazing fact I didn't know about. Do have any reference where I can read about it?

Comment: @CalvinLin, that's entirely trivial, no? Setting $n=1$ in $\sum_{i=1}^n i^k = \sum_{m=0}^{k+1} a_m n^m$ gives that immediately, right?

Comment: Hm yes, you should be able to substitute in a positive integer. Well then, here's another. What is $P(-1)$, the alternating sum of the coefficients?

Comment: @CalvinLin, I haven't found a way to get the alternating sum yet, but I haven't given up. However, I've calculated $a_{k+1}$, $a_k$, and $a_{k-1}$, and I'm wondering if you know if I'm likely to see a pattern if I do more of these calculations—they get longer and longer as $j$ decreases, so if there's nothing to see there, I'll try to come at it from a different direction.

Comment: That said, I'm already starting to wonder whether a previous form I found has something to offer from the linear algebra side of things—I'm a bit rusty on Cramer's rule and such, but I think there may be something down that road.

Comment: As a hint to the alternating sum, show that $x+1 | P(x)$, hence conclude that the value of $P(-1)$ is ... Re pattern of $a_j$, as I said, I'd be amazed if you can find the pattern.

Comment: do you have a link for prove that it is a polynomial in n ?

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh, I don't have a link, no, but if you set up a proof by induction on $n$ *as though you knew what the coefficients are*, you will always be able to choose a high-order coefficient, and then the next one down, etc., so that the inductive step will work regardless of the value of $n$. As for getting drop of intuition to start, the fact that $\int_0^n x^k\,dx = n^{k+1}/(k+1)$ is certainly very suggestive. I really wish I knew a way to refine that integral approximation to get more coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

One hint is that it is far easier to do this is you replace $i^k$ by another polynomial of degree $k$ in $i$, namely by$~\binom ik$. Check that you can find $\sum_{i=0}^n\binom ik$ easily. Then it is theoretically only a question of transforming the basis $[1,i,i^2,\ldots]$ of the polynomial functions in$~i$ to the basis $[\binom i0=1,\binom i1=i,\binom i2=\frac{i(i-1)}2,\ldots]$ and back. In practice this messes the concrete values up considerably.

Comment: What does $\binom i k$ mean when $i<k$?

Comment: It still means $\frac{i(i-1)(i-2)\ldots(i-k+1)}{k!}$. If $i$ is integer and $0\leq i<k$ then this is $0$ because of a factor $i-i=0$ in the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Riemann and Hurwitz zeta functions.

Answer (score 0):

*Please take this not yet as an answer, only it is too long for the comment-box*

Hmm, I thought to help, but I'm not sure that I understand your question at all. If I read your equation correctly, then a coeffcient $a_j$ is explained by the higher ones $a_{j+1}, a_{j+2} ,... a_{k+1}$. So this ( for a certain $k$ ) looks like a matrix equation of the following type $  C*A=A$ where $C$ contains your binomial-coefficients:
$$ \begin{array}{lll}
\begin{array}{lll}
 \end{array}&
*&\begin{bmatrix}
  1\\ a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\\a_5
 \end{bmatrix} \\
\begin{bmatrix}
 c_{1,0}&.&c_{1,2}&c_{1,3}&c_{1,4}&c_{1,5}\\
 c_{2,0}&.&. & c_{2,3}& c_{2,4}& c_{2,5}\\
 c_{3,0}&.&. &. &c_{3,4}&c_{3,5}\\
 .&.&. &. &  1 & .\\
 .&.&. &. & .& 1\\
 \end{bmatrix}&
=&\begin{bmatrix}
 a_1\\a_2\\a_3\\a_4\\a_5\\
 \end{bmatrix} \\ \end{array}$$
but where for instance $a_4$ and $a_5$ are given(?) and are inserted in the upper vector $A$ (and then "computed" into the lower vector $A$).
The iteration begins then that with them and your given coefficents $c_{j,m}$ from there $a_3$ is computed in the lower $A$-vector (and then also inserted in the upper $A$-vector) and then $a_2$ and finally $a_1$.

So for instance , your equation 
$$a_j = \frac{k!}{j!(k-j+1)!}-\sum_{m=j+1}^{k+1}a_{m}\frac{m!}{j!(m-j+1)!}$$
for j=3 and k+1=5 becomes
$$a_3 = \frac{4!}{3!2!}-(a_4\frac{4!}{3!(2)!} + a_5\frac{5!}{3!(3)!}) $$
and this is expressed in the matrix-form by the third row where we get 
$$  a_3 = c_{3,0}+ a_4 c_{3,4} + a_5 c_{3,5} $$
(only where I have made the minus-signs in the coefficients $c_{j,m}$ to make the appearance clearer)
and then $a_2$ can be computed by the second row of the matrix-schema:
$$  a_2 = c_{2,0}+ a_3 c_{2,3}+ a_4 c_{2,4} + a_5 c_{2,5} $$

Is that correct so far?
*(The first idea would then be that this can be handled as an eigenvalue/eigenvector -problem of the matrix $C$ )*

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing there. There definitely does seem to be something very triangular about the equation I found, and you seem to be doing something with that, but I don't quite see what.

Comment: @dfeuer - I'll put an explanation into the answerbox